# SlidingUpPanel button inside of FlatList in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm struggling with SlidingUpPanel & FlatList.
What I want to make is:
FlatList containing with

1. Obj 1
2. Obj 2
3. Obj 3

If I press each objects 1or2or3, I want to pop up the SlidingUpPanel.

What I designed :

```
<SafeareaView>
    <View style={myStyle}>
        <SlidingUpPanel>
            ref={c => (_panel = c)}
            ...
        </SlidingUpPanel>
    </View>
    <FlatList>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _panel.show(height);}>
            ...
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </FlatList>
</SafeAreaView>
```

But it does not works, I'm struggling for a long time.
Actually, I'm not sure that "onPress _panel.show" in FlatList could point "_panel" inside SlidingUpPanel.

Am I missing something? Are there any suggestions or example of SlidingUpPanel & FlatList?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: There might be issues as written here [Not Show View, when have scollview or flatlist inside](https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel/issues/37) and [ScrollView insides the panel - Not work](https://github.com/octopitus/rn-sliding-up-panel/issues/97)

```
<SafeareaView>
    <View style={myStyle}>
       <SlidingUpPanel>
         ref={c => (_panel = c)}
            ...
         <View style={{ height: 236 }}> 
            <FlatList
              data={this.state.locations} 
              renderItem={({ item }) => (
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => _panel.show(height);}>
                   ...
               </TouchableOpacity>
              )} 
              keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()} 
            />
         </View>
      </SlidingUpPanel>
    </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Wrap the ScrollView or FlatList in another View and give height to that View. Like this